# Graphql query with $http.post does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, graphql

The request for the code below goes all ok but I don't get any data back (Just says "Error Not Found" in the "preview" tab of the request in chrome). I try the same query in `GraphiQL` and it gives back relevant data. I am not sure what I am missing here. Please advise, kind of stuck with this.

```
PlayService.prototype.getPlays = function(playID) {
 //The query. 
 const playsQuery = `query ($playid: String) {
    plays(id: $playid) {
      id
      items {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }`;

  // variables to pass.
  const variables = {
    playid: playID
  };

  //The request.
  const result = $http.post(
    /graphql,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ playsQuery, variables })
    }
  );
  return result && result.data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be sending the data body as:

```
{
  playsQuery: "<query string>",
  variables: {}
}
```

The GraphQL spec specifies that you must follow this format for GraphQL queries over REST:

http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/

```
{
  "query": "...",
  "operationName": "...",
  "variables": { "myVariable": "someValue", ... }
}
```